# Column names in a list/multi column criteria in data.table R

Tags: r, data.table, subset

fairly novice in `data.table` so I must be missing something obvious.

```
DT <- data.table(a=1:4,b=c(0,1,2,3),c=c(0,2,0,3),d=c(0,3,2,1),e=c(0,8,5,3))
   a b c d e
1: 1 0 0 0 0
2: 2 1 2 3 8
3: 3 2 0 2 5
4: 4 3 3 1 3
```

I want to select the rows where columns `b`,`c`,`d` and `e` are `==0` without assuming I know the column names before hand. So using a `colNames <- c('b','c','d','e')` vector for it.

I tried

```
DT[all(DT[,colNames]==0)]
```

to no avail obviously.

Any pointers welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Reduce` with `+`

```
DT[DT[, !Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD, `!=`, 0)), .SDcols = colNames]]
#   a b c d e
#1: 1 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: nice as it can easily be modified to fit any condition (as opposed to the other solution where it specifically focus on `==0` due to my question)

Answer (score 1):

`DT[,colNames]` tries to extract a column named `colNames` from `DT`. To take `colNames` as a vector of column names, you can use `..colNames`, and then use `rowSums` to check the condition row wise:

```
DT[rowSums(DT[, ..colNames] != 0) > 0]

#   a b c d e
#1: 2 1 2 3 8
#2: 3 2 0 2 5
#3: 4 3 3 1 3
```

If selecting rows where `b,c,d,e` columns are all zero:

```
DT[rowSums(DT[, ..colNames] != 0) == 0]

#   a b c d e
#1: 1 0 0 0 0
```

---

Another two options:

use `with=FALSE`:

```
DT[rowSums(DT[, colNames, with=FALSE] != 0) > 0]
```

or use `mget`:

```
DT[rowSums(DT[, mget(colNames)] != 0) > 0]
```

Comment: Or `.SDcols` - `DT[DT[,rowSums(.SD != 0) == 0, .SDcols=colNames],]`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The `..` operator does not work in my case for some reason. The rest does. Will validate the second answer because it's cleaner and more generic.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, there is also a `data.table` approach using *join* to subset by variable columns programmatically :

```
library(magrittr) # just for convenience
# create helper table with selection criteria to join with
mDT <- colNames %>% length() %>% rep(0, .) %>% as.list() %>% as.data.table() %>% setnames(colNames)
# join to subset
DT[mDT, on = names(mDT), nomatch = 0L]
```

> ```
>    a b c d e
> 1: 1 0 0 0 0
> ```

The helper table `mDT` looks like:

> ```
>    b c d e
> 1: 0 0 0 0
> ```

---

This approach will also work with other `mDT`, e.g.,

```
mDT <- CJ(a = 3:4, b = 2:3) # cross join
```

> ```
>    a b
> 1: 3 2
> 2: 3 3
> 3: 4 2
> 4: 4 3
> ```

```
DT[mDT, on = names(mDT), nomatch = 0L]
```

> ```
>    a b c d e
> 1: 3 2 0 2 5
> 2: 4 3 3 1 3
> ```